# java does not create dist/lib (Export project)

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jar

I have finished my first small project and I'm struggling with how to export the project to jar then .exe !
I'm using netbeans 8.2 (jdk 8.1), and when I clear and build the dist/lib folder does not appear.

What I have tried :

1-delete nbproject/private

2-select only dependent libraries from build>packaging

3-remove:

```
<not>
    <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
</not>
```

from nbproject\build-impl.xml (but it is not there already)

hierarchy of my project

[image]

dist folder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: the only solution i found is to transfer my project to Intellij..
maybe Eclipse would work too but i did not figure out how to transfer my project to it.

((Note: this solution might not be the best))

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is super outdated (industry-wise), and I would recommend you use Intellij or Eclipse instead.

Granted, I see a .jar and .jnlp in your dist folder so I'm not sure what your issue is.

Please post an update with some clarifying information as to what you are expecting in your dist folder (filenames), as well as the settings you're using to build your project.

Comment: thank you i transfer my project to Intellij and it worked

Comment: the only solution i found is to transfer my project to Intellij.. maybe Eclipse would work too but i did not figure out how to transfer my project to it.